# What is the best practice to reference JavaScript libraries that when installed via NPM (in the node_modules folder)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, node-modules

For example, I created folder, opened it with VS Code. Opened a terminal, used the command `npm install jquery`, it creates a folder node_modules within my created folder. I then create an HTML file, put HTML template in and now I want to reference jQuery. I know how to reference the files syntactically and all that, I am just looking to understand best practices.

Do I just reference jQuery... JavaScript files within there? Or am I missing a step?

Comment: You should probably read [this guide](https://nodesource.com/blog/an-absolute-beginners-guide-to-using-npm/). As a rule of thumb, your `index.html` only loads what's called "entry point" (typically `src/main.js`), which, in turn, builds up the website on the fly from source files (organized in the `src/` folder). Those files are the ones making use of `node_modules/`, as any `import stuff from 'stuff'` will automatically look for a folder called `stuff` in `node_modules/`.

Comment: What are typically called *"modern javascript frameworks"* (react, vue, angular, ... and the list goes on), are all using variations of the above architecture and, inside each of them, you'll find an `index.html` with an empty body, referencing the entry point which, when loaded, builds the entire app by modifying that index.html. The real advantage is that the source of the files is decoupled from the html page, allowing building/serving for different targets and/or environments (minified for production or not minified while developing).

Comment: However, to answer your question, if you want to import anything in your `index.html` directly from `node_modules/`, you have to use a `<script type="module"></script>` tag. Inside that script tag, `import $ from 'jquery'` will work.

Comment: `node_modules` is used by NodeJS applications, NodeJS does not use HTML, NodeJS does not have a DOM so jQuery is useless in a NodeJS application. You need to load jQuery from a CDN or from a local copy on your webserver with a `script` tag.

Answer (score 1):

before starting on a new project you should use `npm init`. this will initialize the project and generate a `package.json` file. This `package.json` file is used for managing the project's dependencies(libraries), scripts, version etc.
And after this every time you install a library using npm it will get listed in this `package.json` file under dependencies section.

example after initializing the npm:

```
  npm i jquery
```

and you can get it using

```
const jquery = require('jquery')
```

or

```
import jquery from 'jquery';
```

i.e; without using the relative path, example:

```
import jquery from '../../node_modules/jquery..'
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are missing the *build* step.

When developing with npm, you usually use a toolchain with compilers, bundlers and minifiers, which read the libraries from the `node_modules` folder and put the resources in a `build` folder which actually gets deployed, and from where the js file will be loaded.